# How to obtain the transfer function of the capacitive sensor?

Tags: sensor, transfer-function, capacitive

I want to obtain the transfer function of this capacitive sensor which in the circuit, C is the  variable capacitor that transforms displacement to electrical signal and E is the dc voltage source after t=0(s). Also, the transfer function in this circuit is acquired by

H(jw)=(())/(1())

where Vo is the voltage of resistor R and X1 is the displacement where was applied to capacitor C.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWEi5y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In addition, V1 is the voltage of capacitor C and the initial distance between the plates of capacitor C is X0.

Thanks

Comment: ....what's your question?

Comment: We need  the area of C and the dielectric (presumably air) to calculate this from displacement.

Comment: Please edit to repair your "transfer function" equation, as it is currently only showing a 1, along with several parenthises.

Comment: The capacitor C's area is A and the permeability of air is assumed e0.

Comment: The question is obtaining the transfer function which was determined.

Answer (score 1):

Assume an initial steady state, so that the capacitor voltage is \$\small E\$ and the charge is \$\small \ Q=EC\$. Now let \$\small \Delta C\$ be a small step change in capacitance at \$\small t=0\$. The capacitor charge will not change instantaneously, hence the capacitor voltage, will decrease instantaneously to:

\$\small V_C =\large \frac{Q}{C+\Delta C}=\frac{EC}{C+\Delta C}\$

The corresponding instantaneous change in capacitor voltage, \$\small \Delta V_C\$, will therefore be:

\$\small \Delta V_C=V_C-E=\large \frac{EC}{C+\Delta C}\small - E=-E(\frac{\Delta C}{C+\Delta C})\$

For small \$\small \Delta C\$ this reduces to:
 \$\small \Delta V_C\approx -E(\frac{\Delta C}{C})\$

where the minus sign indicates that a step increase in capacitance is accompanied by an instantaneous decrease in capacitor voltage.

Now, this instantaneous initial change in capacitor voltage reduces exponentially to zero as current flows through \$\small R\$ from the source \$\small E\$, so we may write the relationship, for \$\small t>0\$ as:

\$\small \Delta V_C(t)= -E(\frac{\Delta C}{C})e^{-t/RC}\$

where the time constant is approximately: \$\small \tau = R(C+\Delta C)\approx RC\small\$.

Taking Laplace transforms, where the input signal step magnitude is \$\small \Delta C\$ and the output signal is \$\small \Delta V_C(s)\$

\$\small \Delta V_C(s)= -\Delta C\large \frac{E}{C}\:\frac{1}{s+1/RC}\$

The last expression is the step response of capacitor voltage, and it is also the voltage response that would be measured across the resistor. To obtain the TF relating voltage change and capacitance change (we are dealing with changes in the variables, so initial conditions are zero and a TF is valid), multiply the step response by s, and treat \$\small \Delta C\$ as a function of time with LT, \$\small \Delta C(s)\$, thus:

\$ \large \frac {\Delta V_C (s)}{\Delta C(s)}= -\frac{E}{C}\frac{s}{s+\small 1/RC}\$

Now you need to relate this TF to the dimensions of the capacitive sensor.